# Change a PNGs color on the fly (PHP/JS)

Tags: javascript, php, css, colors

I am going to have an avatar creation page. I want the user to be able to choose a color of certain elements. I am making the images in layers (over, color, under) with the "color" part being a single color png with alpha.

I want the user to be able to pick a color from a color picker, and see the image update as they do so.

Example: http://hyubusa.com/chatvatars

I am not sure what I'd do exactly to change the color of the eye on the fly as the user is picking colors.

I am hoping to do this with JS and PHP. I appreciate the help in advance.

Comment: is it an avatar of a fly, so you can change the color of his eye?  lol i couldn't resist that one ,  Just kidding you want the GD library  http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php or imageMagic http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php and then gussy it up clientside with a color picker.

Comment: Seems like if all the color images are pre-generated you just have to swap the background-image url to the correct pre-generated PNG.

Comment: @ssnobody - or you could just make an image with transparent areas and then stack some div's behind them and color the background, like the shirt color deal to customize clothing,.

Comment: @ssnobody - the color aren't pregenerated, or I do not want them to be. The shape for the color is (with one basic color). I want the user to have freedom of a color picker to change that color.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix, this would make sense if I masking off the entire image except for the colored area were possible, but I do not think that is a viable solution for me.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix I will look in to the libraries though! Sorry didn't notice you were both of those responses.

Comment: That's fine, image editing is - um how should I put it, archaic at best in php.

Answer (score 0):

Well, @ArtisticPhoenix got me thinking about Masking, and I wondered if CSS could do masking, apparently it can: http://thenittygritty.co/css-masking ... this makes my life a lot easier.

Comment: I've seen it done this way on a number of eCommerce sites, you should thank @ssnobody as well.  That's what made me remember it.